# ALL Bootstrap classes are not found by the Angular CLI

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap with some libraries in my angular project and I have a problem happened suddenly during development. All CSS classes related to bootstrap are not found.

angular.json

```
"styles": [
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss",
          "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss",
          "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular.scss",
          "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands.scss",
          "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/assets/scss/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss",
          "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/assets/scss/mdb.scss",
          "node_modules/animate.css/animate.css",
        "src/styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "./node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
          "./node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"
        ]
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/localize": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~10.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.1",
    "@nebular/date-fns": "^6.2.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.28",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^10.1.1",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  }
```

Comment: What error/ unexpected behavior are you getting?

Comment: the following problem for all bootstrap css classes:
CSS class selector 'text-center' not found.
CSS class selector 'col-3' not found.
and so on ...

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall bootstrap? `npm i --save bootstrap` ?

Comment: yes, but no change

Comment: Check if the path `node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css` exists in your node-modules directory. Also hope you have restarted the server

Comment: I think that you has an "extra " `./` in the paths, try using "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js", and "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js". BTW, you import `bootstrap`and `ng-bootstrap`. The idea of ng-bootstrap is NOT import bootstrap (only the .css)

Answer (score 0):

You need to control path if exists or not at location that you wrote in angular.json
As another simple way you can just add

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

to `index.html` header to apply css classes of bootsrap.

Comment: added but no change?